# Old 1960's Fantasy Film (Possibly Sword & Sandal type movie)

Tags: story-identification, wizards, ghost, underground-civilization

Movie from the 1960's where mad scientist or wizard/warlock keeps people in cage in his underground lair and blinds them with some type of laser or light beam. This could have been a foreign "sword and sandals" movie, like Sampson or Hercules. I also remember an army of ghosts on horseback that could kill live soldiers but could not be hurt themselves. Arrows would pass right through them because...well, they're ghosts! Any idea what movie this was from? It's possible I'm mixing up two different movies.

I saw the movie when I was a kid at Saturday Matinee in my home-town theater in the early 1970's. The matinee was always some Hammer horror film or Italian dubbed Hercules type film. Definitely not *Dark Crystal* or a Lou Farigno movie.

Comment: Blinding with laser beam reminds me of Dark Crystal, but that definitely doesn't have the ghost army (and it was the 80s).  Given the answer below, it may well have been two different movies.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the wizard blinding prisoners, but the rest sounds somewhat like [Sinbad of the Seven Seas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiosdGZnbXPAhWBPZQKHc0BBUUQFgg_MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt0098333%2F&usg=AFQjCNFUzJ2H8KVZyKi89mcDi1gaJQub_g&sig2=3i19lS2MzmXAw5TjxoMPEA). I can see how that might fit the sword and sandal image you remember, and it has the ghost warriors. Was the film you remember definitely from the 60s, or did it just seem so due to cheesy special effects?

Comment: Yes, I saw the movie when I was a kid at Saturday Matinee in my home-town theater in the early 1970's. The matinee was always some Hammer horror film or Italian dubbed Hercules type film. Definitely not Dark Crystal or Lou Farigno movie.

Answer (score 1):

If by **Ghosts** you mean **Skeletons**, then it sounds a bit like **Jason and the Argonauts**. I remember how cool it was when arrows went through them.

[image]

There is a king who was blinded:

From Wikipedia

> The Argonauts next reach the realm of King Phineus (Patrick
>   Troughton), who has been blinded and is tormented by harpies for his
>   transgressions against the gods. In return for his advice on how to
>   reach Colchis, the Argonauts render the harpies harmless by caging
>   them...

Very **Swords and Sandals**.